# Weird arrows in a Haskell heap profile

Tags: haskell, types, heap-profiling

When producing a type heap profile (-hy) from a Haskell program, I get these results:

```
ReaderT
->ReadertT
->>*
(,)
->(#,#)
```

What is the meaning of the '->' prefix (with one or more '>'), the '*' or the '#' here?

Comment: Yikes. That looks like the result of an untested pretty-printer to me. I definitely think that could and probably should be improved. If you're up for taking a shot at it, I suspect GHCHQ would be more than happy to point you at the right place in the enormouse codebase that is GHC, or at least narrow it down to a manageable subset of the whole codebase.